# Inserting Values from 1st database to 2nd Where Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `table1` and `table2`  with the same Column names `topic,brief and description`. I want to copy all the values of the column `brief` from `table1` to `table2` corresponding to values in `topic`.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (brief) 
    SELECT brief 
    FROM dbo.Table1 
    WHERE dbo.Table2.topic = dbo.Table1.topic
```

This gives me an error.

> The multi-part identifier dbo.Table2.topic could not be found.

How to I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update instead of insert

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.brief = t1.brief
FROM dbo.Table2 t2
INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 t1 on t2.topic = t1.topic
```